# Steps to confirm if predicted miRNA is good or bad

Tags: bioinformatics, structure-prediction, microrna

I aligned all miRNAs available to the supercontigs of a particular genome with certain parameters (e value of 0.01 and a word match of atleast 7 as suggested in [this](http://www.hindawi.com/journals/ijg/2012/957607/) paper). I have also isolated the pre-miRNAs (+100 nucleotides from either end of the match area). What would you suggest as ideal ab-initio methods to confirm that these miRNAs do exist in that particular genome? Some papers I found use mFOLD like [this](http://www.scirp.org/journal/PaperDownload.aspx?paperID=6738).

**What would you suggest as best steps to confirm if a predicted miRNA/pre-miRNA is really present in the genome.**

Comment: you can look at my answer in your [previous post](http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/15104/how-do-you-find-pre-mirnas-from-mature-mirna-blast-output).. BTW, How did you obtain the miRNA sequences?

Comment: @WYSIWYG I downloaded all the available mature sequences in miRBase. Removing duplicates is an issue. What would you suggest is a good tool to remove duplicate miRNAs among 30,000 sequences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There won't be any duplicates in miRBase (for a given organism). Choose the taxon nearest to your organism if you are doing homology based discovery. If you want to take all/many organisms then you can use `fastx_collapser` to collapse redundant sequences. However you will lose the name of the miRNA. You can use `awk` also for this and it will keep the sequence header from the first organism in the list.

```
awk '/>/{$0=h} !(/>/){if($0 in a){next} else{a[$0];print h"\n"$0}}' organism1.fa organism2.fa ... organismN.fa
```

*Make sure that there are no extra newlines, otherwise you might need a small modification*

To know if something is an expressed miRNA you would need to do a small RNA sequencing. There are some tools like mirdeep and mirSVR which you can use to discover miRNA sequences.

Comment: Do I really need to use mirDeep now that I am trying to match the already existing list of all available miRNA to the genome rather than find new novel sequences. I thought that was what miRdeep was for.

Comment: It does not just find novel miRNAs but it also checks for the features such as hairpin formation and assigns scores. mirSVR uses a machine learning algorithm to find miRNAs (I have never used it though)